# How to choice what method should be called when use polymorphism

Tags: java, polymorphism, hierarchy

I need a way to choice who method should be called.

I'm calling a parent method who calls one of its methods using "this". The problem is that I override that method in my class so when call the parent method then It calls to my method instead of its method.

```
public class MainTest    
{
    public static class A
    {
       public String m1()
       {
             return this.m2();
       }

       public String m2()
       {
           return "A.m2() called";
       }
    }

    public static class B extends A
    {
        @Override
        public String m1()
        {
          return "B.m1() called";
        }

        @Override
        public String m2()
        {
          return "B.m2() called";
        }

        public String m3()
        {
          return super.m1();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(new B().m3());
    }
}
```

I want to achieve "A.m2() called", but the actual output is "B.m2() called"

Comment: why are you using static classes?

Comment: In which class your main method is ? and why your both class is static ?

Comment: They are probably nested classes in another class. Anyway, you can't do this, unless you make a method in `B` that calls `super.m2()`. Otherwise it would defeat the point of overriding methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have overridden `m2()` in `B`, then only way to get `A.m2()` to run instead of `B.m2()` is to call *`super.m2()` inside `B.m2()`*.

Even if you're calling `super.m1();` in `B.m3()`, the call to `this.m2()` in `A.m1()` will still cause the overridden `B.m2()` to run.

If you don't want to have `super.m2()` inside `B.m2()` (or don't want that in all cases), then the only alternative is to create a different method that you don't override in `B` (and call that from `A.m1()` - you may have to change or create another `A.m1()` too):

```
public static class A {
   public String m1(){ //you may need a different method to call from B.m3()
       return this.anotherM2();
   }
   public String m2(){
       return "A.m2() called";
   }
   public String anotherM2() {
       return "A.m2() called";
   }
}
```

Comment: You could, of course, invoke `anotherM2()` in `m2()`, to save repeating yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you can see the following process:

-B.m3 does super.m1 what means A.m1

-A.m1 does this.m2, where this is B, for that reason B.m2 is being called

Comment: "After removing the static keyword" it is entirely appropriate (and advisable) to make nested classes static if they do not need to refer to an instance of the enclosing class.

Comment: the question was edited in the meantime, before you were not able to see that classes are nested. I have updated also my answer

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, you need to call `super.m2()` in `B.m3`.

Calling `super.m1()` wouldn't work because `A.m1` calls `this.m2()`. `this` is of runtime type `B` (you have never created an `A` object so it can't be of runtime type `A`), so the `m2` in `B` would be called. You can only call `super.m2()` to achieve what you want.